# Python multiple strings point to same heap memory object if value have less than 4 DIFFERENT characters

Tags: python, variables, heap-memory, string-interning, string-pool

in addition to the answers provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51215450/how-does-python-know-two-string-variables-point-to-the-same-object#_=_)

For example :

```
q = "asdasdasdsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsad"
a = "asdasdasdsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsad"

>>> a is q
True
```

even though the strings are long(way longer than 4 characters), python still points to the same object in memory no matter how many times i concatenate "asd", but...

..if i add,lets say "e", that makes the unique characters 4 (a,s,d and e) and python now creates a value object in heap.

```
q = "asdasdasdsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsade"
a = "asdasdasdsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsade"

>>> a is q
False
```

Interesting.

Can someone elaborate on this?

Edit:

Now it is True, but if I add a special character in both variables then it returns False

Comment: Some general background here, but it doesn't cover your specific observation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541404/python-string-interning

Comment: I can reproduce both your examples on Python 3.11. But if I remove the `*` character from the second example, `a is q` is True. I wonder if something special happens for alphabetic characters only?

Comment: This is implementation dependent. There is no requirement it should be like that.

Comment: @slothrop i removed the asterisks from the example.In my side.Python output was True. Now i rerun it it is False.

Comment: @slothrop Indeed i also tried it with non alphanumeric characters and it returns False.

Also, now i always get True with alphanumeric characters and I cannot replicate. duh.

Python 3.11.2

Comment: Interesting - I consistently get `True` for your revised second example (CPython 3.11.0 on Windows - and the same on 3.10.5)

Comment: @trincot Please, elaborate

Comment: See answers in dupe-reference.

Comment: @SpyrosKappalamda a link from that dupe question took me here - http://guilload.com/python-string-interning/ Note the part about "all_name_chars": basically any string with a non-alphanumeric char (except underscore) won't be interned. That page is from the Python 2 days - the relevant bit of the CPython source is now here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/654d44b3a4d3ee4d92b690668aa5189acf4f9d8f/Objects/codeobject.c#L151